# Is there a way to have gradle build a subproject dependency before building another subproject?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a subproject, `:a`, that has a subproject, `:b` as a dependency. How do I make gradle build subproject `:b` before it builds subproject `:a`?

Comment: Gradle will do this automatically. Do you have any specific problem regarding this functionality?

Comment: It turned out to be an issue with a plugin I was using, after I removed it, `:b` was built before `:a` automatically.